# How to Override Power Button In Android Device

Tags: java, android, android-studio

What I'm asking is how I can change what will show up, when I use long press of the power button. Usually it shows Power off, Airplane Mode, Restart, Silent Mode, and whatever it is..

Hope you know what I mean. And I apologize for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You download the Android source code, modify what it shows on the power menu, compile your own version of Android based on your modified code, package that as a custom ROM, and install that ROM on your Android device.

There is no means for an ordinary Android SDK app to affect the power menu.

I cannot rule out the possibility of modifying the power menu on rooted devices (e.g., Xposed framework), though.

Comment: It is fairly easy to modify it using Xposed. There are several modules already doing that, e.g. the popular `GravityBox`.

Comment: @CommonsWare does device owner for newer device can help here?

Comment: @piyush: Not that I know of.